# How many types of surface singularities multiplicity two exist?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, surfaces, singularity-theory

All varieties are over $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $S$ be a reduced algebraic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ with a singular point $p$ of multiplicity two. The question is local so we reduce to $S \subset \mathbb{A}^3$ and $p=0$. Then $S$ is given as the zero set of a polynomial $f = f_2 + f_3 \ldots$ where $f_i$ is homogeneous of degree $i$ and $f_2$ is nonzero (Hartshorne, exercise I.5.3).

The question in the title is vague, so let me split it into parts:

- If the singularity $p$ is isolated, is it necessarily an ordinary quadratic one? (i.e. is it resolved by a single blowup operation, resulting in a rational -2 curve?) If not, what are examples of other possibilities?
- Is it true that $p$ is isolated if and only if its two tangent directions (the linear factors of $f_2$, see again Hartshorne exercise I.5.3) are different?

These two questions are based on intuition and not much more, so i hope they are not totally ridiculous. When answering, any elaboration on the concept of multiplicity and tangent directions is highly appreciated! Thanks!

**Edit:** After learning about Du Val singularities, i realize the first question is pretty stupid.. But then again, the question could be replaced by "Are the Du Val singularities the only surface singularities of multiplicity two?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a surface, the multiplicity of a singular point is the first invariant to look for. Suppose it is a double point. In that case, you want to look for the tangent cone. If the tangent cone is $xy$ then you have an $A_k$ singularity (basically of the form $x^2+y^2+z^k$). If the tangent cone has the form $x^2$. Then, the double point singularity has the form
$$
x^2+g(y,z)
$$
Now, you can use other invariants such a the Milnor number, the modality, etc...
A good place to star is " Singularities of Differentiable Maps: Volume 1: The Classification of Critical Points Caustics, Wave Fronts by V.I. Arnold, S.M. Gusein-Zade, A.N. Varchenko". Go to the index, and look for classification of singularities.